# The 127.0.0.1 page isn’t working .. Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

we develop an application in Laravel .. Before it was working, but not yet. after login it show me this error **The 127.0.0.1 page isn’t working
127.0.0.1 redirected you too many times.**

**Routes**

```
Route::any('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
Route::get('/', 'PageController@login');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::group( ['middleware' => 'auth' ], function() {
    Route::get('main', 'PageController@main');
    Route::get('browse', 'PageController@browse');
    Route::get('pickngo', 'PageController@pickngo');
    Route::get('edit_profile', 'PageController@profile');

    Auth::routes();
    Route::post('/user/create', 'Auth\RegisterController@createUser');
    Route::post('/user/login', 'Auth\LoginController@doLogin');

});
```

Comment: check your AuthController see your `$redirectTo` value after that check the code inside your `$redirectTo` controller

Comment: In Auth directory LoginController have `protected $redirectTo = '/home';`

Comment: Did you run php artisan serve? or how do you serve that app?

Comment: @lewis4u yes absolutly i run `php artisan serve` by Get Bash first

Comment: i guess you have changed something and now it's not working....try to `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan view:clear` and `composer dump-autoload` in the console. And after that try to run it and login

Comment: check your apache error_log

Comment: make sure your laravel directory have the  correct permissions. Make 755 for the root directory and 777 for the storage directoy.

Comment: @Sahil Can you tell how to check permissions?

Comment: if you are using linux you can easily see the permissions  by using the ls -l command

Comment: but i am using Windows so how should i check the permissions??

Comment: you can just use windows composer and do a composer update inside your app folder maybe you have some locking depedencies in your project

Comment: Your Auth::routes() shouldn't be wrapped under auth middleware group

Comment: Can you show us your code on HomeController?

Comment: What was the mistake?

Comment: `Auth::routes();` under the middleware. it shouldn't be under the middle ware

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are using `Auth::routes()` inside `group()`. It is actually wrong because there are many routes wich are having middleware of `guest` (login, register, etc) So it will keep redirecting to the same page in a infinite loop

Try bringing `Auth::routes()` to top or bottom of `Route::group()`